# I can't extract element value in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript and trying to adapt a script I found online but I'm unable to extract the value entered in the first name text field. I don't understand what I'm getting wrong. Please can someone take a look at it please? Thank you.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("fname").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Found " + x;
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm" action="/action_page.php">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br> Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Get it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Change name="fname" to id="fname"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `document.getElementById()` to get the value of your element.

It means your element must have the `id` attribute. In your case, you only have the `name` attribute for your element. So it should be done this way.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form id="myForm" action="/action_page.php">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Get it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("fname").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Found " + x;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I added the `id` attribute to your form elements.